# Topological proof about polygon divided by line in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, polygons

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a compact polygon in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and let $\mathcal{R}$ be a line.

- Show by topological arguments (i.e. using concepts and theorems from general topology) that there exists a line $\mathcal{R'}$ $\mathit{parallel}$ to $\mathcal{R}$ such that $\mathcal{R'}$ divides $\mathcal{P}$ in two parts with $\mathit{equal}$ $\mathit{area}$.

$\\$
$\\$

Remarks:

1. Specifying that $\mathcal{P}$ is compact may be superfluous since it is closed and bounded in $\mathbb{R}^2$
2. The main difficulty I find to even try sketching a proof is that I don't know how to translate in topological language the fact that the two parts of $\mathcal{P}$ must have the same area.

(Edit) Sketched proof attempt:

Choose a cartesian system of axes with the $X$ axis superimposed on $\mathcal{R}$, and the $Y$ axis directed in such a way that the polygon lies above the $X$ axis.
Now define a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for $y \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(y)$ is the difference between the two areas in which the line parallel to the $X$ axis at height $y$ divides the polygon. Now $f$ is continuous and assumes the values $A$ and $-A$, where $A$ is the area of the polygon, before and after reaching it. $\mathbb{R}$ is connected, therefore the Intermediate Value Theorem holds and $f$ must be zero somewhere in between.

Comment: "How much" topology do you know?  I know a theorem that does this, but I never teach it until algebraic topology.

Comment: Ah wait, this might be arguable from a simple connectedness/IVT style argument.

Comment: If impossible with connectedness or compactness alone, basics of algebraic topology are allowed (such as fundamental groups, homotopy, homotopy equivalence).

Comment: I see now that in the book by Munkres there's a theorem about polygons (Bisection Theorem) that may be useful; it follows from Borsuk-Ulam theorem for $S^2$. What's strange is that my professor seems not to have taught neither of these in the course and I found this exercise in the test today, therefore my suspicion that it can be proved without them.

Comment: Yes, the Borsuk-Ulam theorem is what I had in mind.

Comment: There are three coneptual issues. 1) How do you define the area of a polygon $P$? As an integral? 2) You have to show that the intersection of a polygon $P$ with any half plane $H_\pm(L)$ (above or below a line $L$) is again a polygon. 3) You have to show that the area function (area of the polygon $P \cap H_+(L)$) is continuous as a function of $L$. Then apply the IVT.

Comment: First of all you can choose a coordinate system in such way that $R$ is the $Y$-axis and $R'$ is given by $L_y=\{(x,y)\ |\ x\in\mathbb{R}\}$. Now if $P$ is the polygon then you can define $f(z)$ as area of $\{(x,y)\in P\ |\ y\leq z\}$. You can normalize it by dividing by area of $P$. And then you solve $f(z)=1/2$. The solution exists by IVT if $f$ is continuous. And it is if by "area" you mean Lebesgue measure (and in that case $P$ being of finite measure is enough). BTW there's no way to solve that without refering to some measure theory. So searching for pure topological proof is pointless.

Comment: Anyway it boils down to the definition and properties of "area".